# MVC4 Google font and minify

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cdn

I have an @import statement in one of my css files... all my css files are bundled/minified, and apparently that is not kosher as I get an error:

```
run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@import'
```

The import is a font from Google.
What is the proper way to handle CDN in MVC4?

thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was embarrassingly simple...

In BundleConfig.cs :

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;

// bundles code

var cdnPath = "path to your resource (font in my case)";
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/fonts", cdnPath));
```

Then in layout

```
@Styles.Render("~/fonts")
```

Comment: Note that this just circumvents bundling and includes a separate link tag for your font resource.  I think the issue is that imports have to precede all other rules in a css file, so the bundler would potentially end up moving your imports before other rules when merging them into a single file.